Image weird resizing behaviour when refreshing
When I refresh the page (below's a gif)

The Image is resized in a weird way.
            <WifiWidgetContainer>
              <Image
                src={`/assets/wifi@5x.png`}
                alt="wifi_icon"
                objectFit="contain"
                fill
              />
            </WifiWidgetContainer>


const WifiWidgetContainer = styled(Box)({
  width: 20,
  height: 20,
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center",
  position: "relative",
});

I want to the Image not resizing on reloading visually.
I tried to comment objectFit="contain", it doesn't resize anymore but that's not the Image size I want. How to fix that?

I don't know if this answers your question exactly. But your syntax for the Next Image tag is wrong. There are 4 required props
'The Image Component requires the following properties: src, width, height, and alt.
There are other props available, listed here https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/components/image
objectContain is not a valid prop, you can make additional styling changes within the style prop...
<Image>
...
style={{  
       objectFit: "contain"

             }}
</Image>


I did try this solution but having the same UX
